# How to implement PHP Checkbox Processing and update MySQL database accordingly

Tags: php, html, mysql

My goal is to allow a user to update whether multiple members are currently active. Let me explain what I have  done so far.

This is what my form/table looks like in a browser:

[image: Table Exmaple]

The only section that can be modified is obviously the "Current Publisher" column with the checkbox inputs.  This is the code that produces the table:

```
public function selectAllMembers()
        {
            //Declerations
             $i =""; 

            $stmt = $this->dbh->prepare("SELECT UserId, Firstname, Lastname, Active, UserPriv FROM Members;"); //Select ALL data from table, Perhaps had a limit later 
            $stmt->execute(); //Execute the query
            $result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_NUM); //Fetch all of the data

            //Display results
            echo "<form name=\"UpdateUser\" method=\"Post\" action=\"\">";
            echo "<table border='1'>
            <tr>
            <th>User Id </th>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
            <th>Current Publisher</th>
            <th>User Priveleges</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>";

            if($result == false) 
                echo "<td>For some reason, there are no memebers.</td></tr></table>"; //Just in case there are no members...:)

            else
            {
                foreach($result as $row)
                    foreach($row as $col)
                    {

                        $i++;

                        switch ($i) { 
                            case 4: //Is it a current publisher?
                                if($col == 0) 
                                    echo "<td><input type=\"checkbox\" class=\"current\" value=\"1\" ></td>";
                                else
                                    echo "<td><input type=\"checkbox\" class=\"current\" value=\"1\" checked ></td>";
                                break;

                            case 5: //Do they have user priveleges?
                                if($col == 0)
                                    echo "<td>No</td>";
                                else
                                    echo "<td>Yes</td>";
                                echo "</tr><tr>"; //start a new row
                                $i=0; //reset counter
                                break;

                            default:
                                echo "<td>$col</td>";

                        }

                    }
                echo "</tr></table>";
                echo "</form>";
            }
        }
```

Case 4 and Case 5 in the switch statement determines whether it is true or false (I use either a 1 or a 0 in the MySQL database for true or false respectively). Also in case 4 I translate the true or false into an input checkbox.

What I want to do is upon submission (I don't have submit button for my form yet), have a function that can compare any changes to column "Current Publisher." If there are any changes, update the respective table. Right now, everyone is active. Say Bob Smith is no longer active, I would want his value in the table to change to false.

I'm having several issues implementing this.

1) How do I modify my checkboxes in such a way that they can be compared/processed with PHP?  This is what they are right now:

```
<input type="checkbox" value="1">
```

I have seen a few examples about how to submit multiple checkboxes and subsequently process them with PHP. For instance, I could possibly modify them as such:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="member[]" value="1">
```

What I was thinking, though, is using User Id as the name, as that will always be unique. I could also then use that in a SQL query to identify the correct user.

2) How do I update my table based on the input? Should I simply update everything with an update query, or look simply for what values were changed? What would be most efficient?

Any help would be appreciated - especially in the form of examples. If there are any questions, just put them in the comments. I hope I conveyed the crux of what I am wanting to do.

Note: There is also the issue of checkboxes not submitting if they are not "checked." Are there any workarounds for this? I've seen a javascript workaround, but that is assuming the user has javascript enabled (I don't know who doesn't anymore, but I should at least consider the possibility).

Answer (score 0):

Considering the content, you must only print the "Firstname/Last Name/Current Publisher/User Privilege" and leaving the User ID;

Instead!, use the User ID as a link. I know you know how to create basic tables, you may add this kind of options

**@testallmembers.php**

```
    <table>
        <tr>
           <td><a href="edit.php?id=<?php echo $row['user_id']?>">Edit</a></td>
           <td>F_NAME</td>
           <td>L_NAME</td>
           <td>CURRENT_PUBLISHED</td>
           <td>USER_PRIVILEGE</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Using the $row['user_id'], or whatever row index you have in your sql, should be editable.

**@edit.php**

In you edit.php you must use do this

```
    if(isset($_GET['id']) && !empty($_GET['id'])) {
        /*
        * use mysqli_real_escape_string to quote the id, for anti sql attacks
        * if you know PDO then use predefined.
        */

        //[SQL CODE HERE] - search the $_GET['id'] basing from the user_id

        /* then print the "EDITABLE FORM" 
        *  SAMPLE: <form method='post' action='edit.php'>
        *               <input type='text' name='f_name' value='<?php $row['f_name']?>' />
        *               <input type='submit' name='submit'/>
        *          </form>  
        */  

    //using $_POST['submit'] to get the EDITABLE form
    }elseif(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        /*
        *   Save the values to your database, you also need to check first the input values for anti sql injection..
        */
    }
```

Comment: That is certainly an option. Thanks for your input.

Comment: If it helps, then you may +1 and Check the answer...so that others may also have the options to find the correct one...

Answer (score 0):

I think you are dealing with db result (associate array).
Try this:

```
$stmt = $this->dbh->prepare("SELECT UserId, Firstname, Lastname, Active, UserPriv FROM Members;"); //Select ALL data from table, Perhaps had a limit later 
$stmt->execute(); //Execute the query
$result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_NUM); //Fetch all of the data

//..... your html.....

for ($i = 0; $i < count($result); $i++)
{
    if($result[$i]['currentPublisher'] == 0) 
    {
      echo "<td><input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"$result[$i]['currentPublisher']\" class=\"current\" value=\"0\" ></td>";
      // NOTE: The value need to be 0   
    }
    else
    {
       echo "<td><input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"$result[$i]['currentPublisher']\" class=\"current\" value=\"1\" checked ></td>";
    }
}

//..... your html.....
```